# Override generic method

Tags: java, generics, overriding

According to [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) (Java Language Specification):

> The notion of subsignature is designed to express a relationship between two methods whose signatures are not identical, but in which one may override the other. Specifically, it allows a method whose signature does not use generic types to override any generified version of that method.

This code is based on the JLS example:

```
interface CollectionConverter<U> {
    <T> List<T> toList(Collection<T> c);

    void fooMethod(Class<?> c);

    <E>Comparable<E> method3(E e);

    Comparable<U> method4(U u);
}

class Overrider implements CollectionConverter<Integer> {
    @Override
    public List toList(Collection c) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void fooMethod(Class c) {

    }

    @Override
    public  Comparable method3(Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    // compile error, have to change Object to Integer 
    public Comparable method4(Object u) {                       

        return null;
    }
}
```

According to the JLS, I understand why the first three methods work well, but I can't figure out why `method4` has this compilation error:

> The method method4(Object) of type Overrider must override or implement a supertype method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `method4` in `CollectionConverter` is

```
Comparable<U> method4(U u);
```

You declare `Overrider` to implement `CollectionConverter<Integer>`, thereby binding the type parameter `U` to `Integer`. The signature then becomes:

```
Comparable<Integer> method4(Integer u);
```

You can declare a `method4(Object u)` in `Overrider`, but that method signature does not override `method4(Integer u)` specified in the interface any more than it would if you weren't using generics at all.

Comment: However, after type erasure, all the type parameters replaced by Object or the first bound in the "extends" list. Just like the first three methods, after erasure the first three methods' signatures are exactly the same as the ones in Overrider class. Following this lead, the signature and return type of method4 should be: Comparable method4(Object u) which is the same as the one in Overrider. So, this is my question

Comment: @RobyYan - Generics are not just syntactic sugar for down-casting from the least upper bound. Type erasure kicks in _after_ the compiler checks for type safety. The whole idea of generics is to enable the compiler to do type checking for you. Forcing the compiler to do its analysis as if type erasure had already been applied would be hopeless; there'd be almost nothing left for it to work with.

Comment: "The whole idea of generics is to enable the compiler to do type checking for you. Forcing the compiler to do its analysis as if type erasure had already been applied would be hopeless; there'd be almost nothing left for it to work with." Got it, I almost forget the original purpose of generics, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the type variable `U` is bound to `Integer` at that point. If you change the declaration to

```
public Comparable method4(Integer u) ...
```

it is an override

Answer (score 1):

Because in the interface, method4 is declared with the same type parameter as the interface (U). If you change it to something else, it should work.

For example

```
<A> Comparable<A> method4(A a);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of wanting to override a method with a generic param, which does not have a generic return type, you need to make sure type of the param is actually a child of the that generic type.

For example:

```
protected Response updateResource(long id, T payload, RequestContext context){}
```

is overriden by

```
@Override
protected Response updateResource(long id, Payload payload, RequestContext context){}
```

Thumbs up for the IntelliJ IDEA's Code > Generate... > Override Methods...

Comment: You are only showing how to gererate overide methode but you can not force to use Intellij.